# Catching notifications using Accessibility Service Android app

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an app in which one of the tasks is to catch the notifications of different applications (phone call, Facebook, Twitter, Whatsapp etc...). Now I will have some values pre-defined for all the pre-defined applications. Values will be of type string denoting R,G,B color values. I would have to send these color values via Bluetooth to another device. For this I have created an accessibility service.

Here is my main activity:

Main Activity displays a listview with applications name declared in the `currentlyEnabled` `HashMap`. The `newFinalPackages` `HashMap` stores the application names for all the pre defined applications. The `apptoRBG` `HashMap` stores these application names with user-given RGB values.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Intent mailAccessabilityIntent;
    private ListView actioList;
    private ActionCustomAdapter adapter;
    private static final String DEFAULT_COLOR = "R:255,G:255,B:255";
    private static HashMap<String, String> newfinalpackages = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> newappToRGB = new HashMap<String, String>();

    static {
        newfinalpackages.put("dialer", "Calls");
        newfinalpackages.put("whatsapp", "WhatsApp");
        newfinalpackages.put("facebook.katana", "Facebook");
        newfinalpackages.put("twitter", "Twitter");
        newfinalpackages.put("instagram", "Instagram");
        newfinalpackages.put("gmail", "GMail");
        newfinalpackages.put("batterylow", "Low Battery");
        newfinalpackages.put("messenger", "Text Message"); 

        newappToRGB.put("dialer", DEFAULT_COLOR);
        newappToRGB.put("whatsapp", DEFAULT_COLOR);
        newappToRGB.put("facebook", DEFAULT_COLOR);
        newappToRGB.put("twitter", DEFAULT_COLOR);
        newappToRGB.put("instagram", DEFAULT_COLOR);
        newappToRGB.put("gmail", null);
        newappToRGB.put("batterylow", null);
        newappToRGB.put("messenger", null);
    }


    private static HashMap<String, String> currentlyEnabled = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private HashMap<String, String> currentlyDisabled = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static HashMap<String, String> getCurrentlyEnabled() {
        return currentlyEnabled;
    }

    public static HashMap<String, String> getAppToRGB() {
        return newappToRGB;
    }

    private void DrawSelected() {
        currentlyEnabled.put("dialer", "Calls");
        currentlyEnabled.put("whatsapp", "WhatsApp");
        currentlyEnabled.put("facebook", "Facebook");
        currentlyEnabled.put("twitter", "Twitter");
        currentlyEnabled.put("instagram", "Instagram");
        currentlyDisabled.put("gmail", "GMail");
        currentlyDisabled.put("batterylow", "Low Battery");
        currentlyDisabled.put("messenger", "Text Message");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent mailAccess = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InstantMessanger.class);
        startService(mailAccess);
        DrawSelected();
        serviceSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.serviceSwitch); //DIDN'T ADD FUNCTIONALITY YET.
        actioList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.actionList);

         // Button to add applications from currentlyDisabled to CurrentlyEnabled
         // Not Important here.
        actioList.addFooterView(addEvent);
        adapter = new ActionCustomAdapter(this, currentlyEnabled);    
        actioList.setAdapter(adapter);

           // Just to choose the color value.Nothing Else.
        actioList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String Item = ((HashMap.Entry<String, String>) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).getKey();
                showColorPickerDialogDemo(Item);
            }
        });

    }

        // IGNORE THIS.
    private void showColorPickerDialogDemo(final String key) {

        int initialColor = Color.WHITE;

        ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog(this, initialColor, new ColorPickerDialog.OnColorSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onColorSelected(int color) {
                showToast(color);
                appToRGB.put(key, "R: " + Color.red(color) + " B: " + Color.blue(color) + " G: " + Color.green(color));
                InstantMessanger.addEnabledActions(key, "R: " + Color.red(color) + " B: " + Color.blue(color) + " G: " + Color.green(color));
            }

        });
        colorPickerDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

`showColorPickerDemo()` is for color selection.

My service class is:

When created, the `enabledAction` `HashMap` from `MainActivity` is passed to this class using static methods.

The service class basically catches any notification posted on an Android device by any application with the listener `OnAccessibility` event. Then it is extracting the actual application name from the package name in the `parsePackage()` method. Then it checks if this application name is in `enabledActions`. If yes, it sends the data through Bluetooth (which still needs to be implemented).

```
public class InstantMessanger extends AccessibilityService {

    private TextView text;
    private String packagename;
    private String selfname = "com.example.sgoel01.checkingevents",download = "com.android.providers.downloads";
    Context context = this;

    private static HashMap<String,String> enabledActions = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void addEnabledActions(String key, String value) {
        enabledActions.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Started for the first time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        enabledActions = MainActivity.getAppToRGB();
        for(HashMap.Entry<String,String> entry : enabledActions.entrySet()) {
            Log.d("enabledAct", entry.getKey() + " is equal to " + entry.getValue());
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, enabledActions.get("whatsapp"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Started on startcommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        enabledActions = MainActivity.getAppToRGB();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        //Toast.makeText(this,"Event Catched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
            packagename = String.valueOf(event.getPackageName());
            Log.d("pack/call", packagename);
            parsePackage(packagename);
            if(packagename.equals(selfname)==false && packagename.equals("com.android.providers.downloads")==false) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Package: "+packagename,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(enabledActions.get(packagename) != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This is Working Now " + packagename , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    private void parsePackage (String pack) {
        String name = pack.substring(pack.indexOf(".")+1,pack.length());
        char[] array = pack.toCharArray();
        int prev=0;
        for(int i=0,n=pack.length() ; i<n ; i++) {
            String temp="";
            if(i==n-1) {
                temp = pack.substring(prev,i+1);
                Log.d("seetothis", "Name: " + temp +" has value= " + enabledActions.get(temp) );
            }
            else if(pack.charAt(i) == '.') {
                temp = pack.substring(prev,i);
                prev = i+1;
                Log.d("seetothis", "Name: " + temp +" has value= " + enabledActions.get(temp) );
            }
            if(enabledActions.get(temp) != null) {
                Log.d("printout", "Package grabbed is: "+temp+" With Value: "+enabledActions.get(temp));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }

    public static String gettheColor() {
        return enabledActions.get("dialer");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hUA Nhi ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.feedbackType = 1;
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.notificationTimeout = 100;
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }

}
```

Here is my custom adapter for listview on main activity. This is taking the `HashMap`s and simply displaying in listview.

```
public class ActionCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList mData;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public ActionCustomAdapter(Activity a, HashMap<String,String> d) {
        activity = a;
        mData = new ArrayList();
        mData.addAll(d.entrySet());
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap.Entry<String, String> getItem(int position) {
        return (HashMap.Entry) mData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_notification, null);

        HashMap.Entry<String, String> item = getItem(position);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textAction);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageAction);

        text.setText(item.getValue());
        return vi;
    }


}
```

Am I declaring too many static methods and variables? Am I passing too much data between the activities?

Also, my service intend to run in the background, so do I need a different set of variables (corresponding string values for different applications) for it always, or can I just extract them from another activity whenever required? Or there is some better way?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(packagename.equals(selfname)==false && packagename.equals("com.android.providers.downloads")==false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Package: "+packagename,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You can use this check instead:

```
!packagename.equals(selfname) && !packagename.equals("com.android.providers.downloads")
```

Explicit equality checks with `false` seem out of place.

---

```
private void parsePackage (String pack) {
    String name = pack.substring(pack.indexOf(".")+1,pack.length());
    char[] array = pack.toCharArray();
    int prev=0;
    for(int i=0,n=pack.length() ; i<n ; i++) {
        String temp="";
        if(i==n-1) {
            temp = pack.substring(prev,i+1);
            Log.d("seetothis", "Name: " + temp +" has value= " + enabledActions.get(temp) );
        }
        else if(pack.charAt(i) == '.') {
            temp = pack.substring(prev,i);
            prev = i+1;
            Log.d("seetothis", "Name: " + temp +" has value= " + enabledActions.get(temp) );
        }
        if(enabledActions.get(temp) != null) {
            Log.d("printout", "Package grabbed is: "+temp+" With Value: "+enabledActions.get(temp));
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than using a complex loop here, you could make use of [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), then iterate over the String array afterwards. As `String.split` takes a regex, you'll want to escape the delimiter:

(Escape method taken from [How can I use “.” as the delimiter with String.split() in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755945/how-can-i-use-as-the-delimiter-with-string-split-in-java))

```
String[] packageNames = pack.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much. Also I want to ask if there can be any improvement to the object oriented aspect of the program.

Comment: Anymore comments sir ?

Comment: @user3800101 sorry, I'm not familiar with Android's recommended way to split up classes. If you had a object hierarchy separate from android then I could help but I haven't programmed a whole lot of Android before... so I just reviewed it based on the fact you can use regular Java for android